# Paginating "KEYS" command on Redis

Tags: python, redis

I need all the keys in **redis** matching a given pattern : `*_xyz_*`, then I get all their values by following **python** code:-

```
  def get_keys(self,pattern):
    self.r_prod.keys(pattern);
    keys = self.r_prod.execute();

    for i in keys[0]:
      self.r_prod.get(i);
    return self.r_prod.execute();
```

Now `keys` is pretty huge to hold all in the memory. So, I am wondering is there any way to paginate keys call for a certain limit?

Comment: You need to use `scan` for this purpose. http://redis.io/commands/scan

Comment: You can use SSCAN, https://christophermcdowell.dev/post/pagination-with-redis/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [SCAN](http://redis.io/commands/scan) command:

```
>>> import redis
>>> r = redis.Redis()
>>> for x in r.scan_iter('dummy*'):
...   print(x)
... 
b'dummy3'
b'dummy2'
b'dummy1'
```

Comment: Thanks, but is it possible to scan in a pipeline? or more precisely does scan command takes a TCP connection for every iteration or implicitly creates a pipeline?

Comment: Ok got my answer, it creates an new call at each iteration, but I could limit the iteration: https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py/blob/master/redis/client.py#L1372